# Radio button check in JS not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think I'm being super obtuse here, so made a fiddle, why is it that whenever I check another radio button, it's not staying checked?

In the fiddle, it will load with the button for "diy" checked; if you click on "paid", you'll see the radio button jump to there when the alert loads, but then jump back, even though the JS statements work independently in the console. Help appreciated! (Btw, I tried 2 ways of checking, both failed)

https://jsfiddle.net/gzf28hsk/

This is the function that's likely breaking, but I don't know where

```
function populateLogistic(type, new_status = null) {
  radio_paid = $('input[name="delivery"][value="paid"]')
  radio_diy = $('input[name="delivery"][value="diy"]')

  if (new_status === null) {
      radio_paid.prop("checked", false)
      radio_diy.prop("checked", true)
  } else if (new_status == "paid") {
      alert(new_status)
      //radio_paid.checked = true
      //radio_diy.checked = false
      radio_paid.prop("checked", true)
      radio_diy.prop("checked", false)
  } else if (new_status == "diy") {
      //radio_paid.checked = false
      //radio_diy.checked = true
      radio_paid.prop("checked", false)
      radio_diy.prop("checked", true)
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? What's the end goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen to the `change` event instead.

**Update**

Actually the problem was that you were doing `e.preventDefault();` inside the event handler, canceling the event and *undoing* the click.

Anyway, it's better to listen to the `change` event for input changes, because there you're sure that the value have actually changed and because it's also triggered if the input changes without click, for example using the keyboard.

This said, you can (or should) get the selected option with `$('input[name="delivery"]:checked').val()` instead of `$(this).val()`

Comment: worked, but sorry can you explain that one more time? i'm not quite getting it

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: oh interesting. the `e.preventDefault()` was there to prevent the button click from submitting the form. interesting that it undid the click and yet works with `change` event

Comment: You don't need to do that because the click in a radio button doesn't submit the form. It still works because you can't cancel the `change` event because the change already happened. It's like trying to cancel a key press, `keydown` can be cancelled but `keyup` don't because the key stroke already ended.